# Django SessionWizardView reloads the same page when submiting

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I had it working fine using a single template, but then i wrote different html for different forms extending a common base html and while submitting the last form the wizard reloads the last form and does not execute done method.

Heres my url.py:

```
url(r'^settings/new/$', settings_view, name = 'new_settings'),
```

**View**:

```
FORMS = [
    ("Basic", BasicSettingsForm),
    ("Calculation", CalculationForm)
]

TEMPLATES = {
    "Basic":"settings/basic-settings.html",     
    "Calculation":"settings/calculation_settings_form.html"
}

class WizardView(SessionWizardView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        return self.instance_dict.get(step, None)

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(WizardView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        return form

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        b_form = form_list[0]
        c_form = form_list[1]
        try: 
            b_data = b_form
            b_data.save()
            c_data = c_form
            c_data.save()
            message = ''
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            message = "Could not save the settings"
        return message_view(self.request, message = message)

@login_required
def attendance_settings_view(request):
    attWizardView = WizardView.as_view(FORMS)
    return attWizardView(request)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load i18n %} 
<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 
{% block wizardform %}

{% endblock %}
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
     <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit"
     value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Back" %}</button>
{% endif %} 
{% if wizard.steps.current == wizard.steps.last %}
    <input class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans " Finish " %}"/>
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans " Next " %}" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
{% endif %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I suspect that you don't render (non)form errors in your template, and your form is not valid. Perhaps it helps when you also post the content of the rest of the templates.

Comment: ah yes, Validation caused me that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These errors usually occur, if the form does not validate correctly. I usually include all fields and test it, before adapting the fields (e.g. hiding some fields).